# Find lowest and highest value of function $f(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{2t-2}{t^2-2t+2}}dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Find highest and lowest value of function:
$$f(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{2t-2}{t^2-2t+2}}dt$$

We need to use first derivative test to find critical points.

$$f'(x) = \frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x+2}(x)' - \frac{0-2}{0-0+2}(0)'$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{2(x-1)}{x^2-2x+2} = 0$$
$$x = 1$$

What to do now? Should I calculate second derivative $f''(x)$ to check whether it's local minimum or maximum? What could be another critical point to seek for?

Edit: also, do you have any suggestions on how to check the solution on WolframAlpha?

Comment: You can avoid to compute the second derivative simply looking at the sign of $f'$: the denominator is alway positive, so $f'$ is negative for $x<1$ and positive for $x>1$, hence the $x=1$ is a minimum point.

Answer (score 0):

Derive $f'(x)$ properly by noting that

$f(x)=ln(x^2-2x+2)-ln2=ln((x-1)^2+1)-ln2$.

Thus

$f'(x)=\frac{2x-2}{(x-1)^2+1}$

Hence $f'(1)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ when $x>1$, $f'(x)<0$ when $x<1$. So $f(1)=0$ is an absolute minimum.

Comment: How about another possible critical points? Are there any?

Comment: Since the integrand is a continuous, $f$ is at least $C^1$. Thus the only extrema are given by the zeros of $f'$. $f$ has thus just a global minimum and as Maestro13 pointed out it is unbounded from above. To get an idea  of this you can look at the plot $f(x)$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5Bx%5E2-2x%2B2%5D-Log%5B2%5D

Comment: Why isn't this answer accepted?